# I can't login in Debian server with putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, debian, vps

I use putty in windows to login in my Debian server. But when I set my server address and type root username and type server password putty shows

> access denied for password

Now how can I fix that to access server?

Comment: Login using a user account and then suddenly to root

Comment: There is no other account only the root account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first check SSH-server config at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in Debian. Perhaps there can be any parameter that denied remote access.

Comment: how can i access to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` form windows?

Answer (score 0):

Like Cazorla said if you are using debian

do this

1. Login as debian using ssh or any desired terminals
2. write `sudo su` to switch to root user
3. `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
4. a file pops up, find  `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` and change it to `#PermitRootLogin yes`
5. Press ctrl x, press y
6. press enter

You should be able to login as root